# limit with integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Suppose that $f$ is a real valued function, continuous in a neighborhood
of $0$
How can I demonstrate that:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_0^h f(x)\,dx}{h} = f(0)\nonumber
\end{equation}

Many thanks in advance,

-- 
Cesar

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Hint: Use the mean value theorem for integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
the primitive of $f(x)$ is $F(x)$ defined by:
$$\int_0^h f(x)\,dx=F(h)-F(0)$$

hence the limit follows from the fact that $F'(x)=f(x)$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{equation}
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_0^h f(x)\,dx}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\dfrac{d}{dh}\int_0^h f(x)\,dx}{1}=\lim_{h\to0}f(h)
\end{equation}
Thus, $\lim_{h\to0}f(h)=f(0)$ since $f(x)$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: It should say $\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)$ instead of $f(h).$

Answer (score 1):

Write it as
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_0^h \left( f(t)-f(0) \right)\, dt}{h}
$$
and use the fact that the integrand is $< \varepsilon$ provided that $h<\delta$ to conclude:
$$
\left|
\frac{\int_0^h \left( f(t)-f(0) \right)\, dt}{h}
\right|
\leq \frac{h \varepsilon}{h}=\varepsilon.
$$